# How can I keep Visual Studio from adding a reference to my Unit Tests project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a conditional reference (based on build configuration for x86 vs x64) in my project, and when I generate unit tests for an object (by right clicking on the class name and selecting "Create Unit Tests...") Visual Studio (2012) insists on adding a reference to my unit test project for the x86 version of the dll.  The only problem is that this reference already exists in the same conditional form as it does in my main project.

Most of the time I don't realize this happens until I go to merge it up to our UAT environment to build for a different configuration.  At this point it breaks because the UAT environment requires the x64 dll.

Is there any way to work around this <strike>bug</strike> feature?

If it makes any difference, here is the conditional reference:

```
<Reference Include="ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <HintPath>..\References\ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x86.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Dev' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'Test' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'Production'">
  <HintPath>..\References\ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x64.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

And this is the reference that Visual Studio is trying to add, presumably because it can't reconcile that the conditional reference is equivalent:

```
<Reference Include="ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x86, Version=1.0.1.15925, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09b5ce0d5c0a9d8b, processorArchitecture=x86">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\References\ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x86.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I was able to come up with is to add the reference like:

```
<Reference Include="ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x86" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <HintPath>..\References\ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x86.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x64" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Dev' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'Test' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'Production'">
  <HintPath>..\References\ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x64.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I am not 100% sure, but I believe the reason this works (or maybe more accurately, why it wasn't working before) is because the `Include="<AssemblyName>"` matches the name of the dlls, so when the Unit tests are created, Visual Studio sees it as the same reference and doesn't attempt to add it again.